# difficulty using ffmpeg with hardware acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg

I have used `ffmpeg -i VID_20210426_044355366.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast abc.mp4` so just using libx264 the software encoder. And the default CRF is fine for me in terms of quality. And that preset ultrafast is fine for me re quality.

But i'm wondering if I can get it even faster.  I don't mind sacrificing some quality, for speed.

My laptop has an Intel Core i5 processor.    So maybe I have access to some hardware encoding?

I tried

`ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -hwaccel qsv -vcodec h264_qsv abc.mp4`

but it gave me some errors

```
G:\>ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec h264_qsv blah.mp4
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'aaa.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2021-04-26T03:30:13.000000Z
    com.android.version: 10
    com.android.manufacturer: motorola
    com.android.model: moto g(7) power
  Duration: 00:09:10.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17326 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m), 1920x1080, 17000 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25.04 fps, 25 tbr, 90k
 tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 270
      creation_time   : 2021-04-26T03:30:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 319 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-26T03:30:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
File 'blah.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000000005414700] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[h264_qsv @ 0000000000404dc0] Error initializing the encoder: invalid video parameters (-15)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width
or height
Conversion failed!

G:\a>ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec h264_qsv blah.mp4
```

This is in yellow "deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly"

This is in red  "Error initializing the encoder: invalid video parameters (-15)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width
or height"

And it says "Conversion failed".

I get a similar result if I do  `ffmpeg  -hwaccel qsv -i aaa.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec h264_qsv blah.mp4`

I see that these pages could be relevant https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync  and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro  but i'm not sure what to try

Comment: Do you really want to use ffmpeg, or could it be a solution to use some other tool? If it is, you could have a look at DonMelton's other_video_transcoding project. In fact it leverages ffmpeg, but has some internal calculations and modifications that make it really fast while maintaining brilliant quality. https://github.com/donmelton/other_video_transcoding

Comment: I might have a look at that one though ffmpeg has quite a community of users.  ffmpeg is a very difficult tool.. It has taken me a long time to get used to even some of the basics of ffmpeg.

Comment: I know that ffmpeg is a very difficult tool, that’s why I did some research for other tools as I didn’t understand it at first try, and I am more in doing research for another tool that works for my needs than learning something too difficult. And the developer is DonMelton is very active on GitHub as well as the whole community, getting help if the documentation is not sufficient is very easy and fast

Comment: @DarkDiamond I find that if I have a raw MP4 from my phone and I try to convert it to an MP4 that is H264:MP3 then.  I can do `ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast` and it's fast like speed  1.9x  Whereas if I use othertranscode it probably does higher quality but is slower  `other-transcode --hevc VID_20210426_162143235.mp4`  speed 0.1x    https://gist.github.com/gartha1/ec120025ec48ca5d839d912ea7058de1    If I could get ffmpeg to use hardware encoding then ffmpeg might be faster even than the 1.9x speed

Comment: My experience is that other_transcode goes to speeds of 15x and more, on my laptop, which is no high end device, I need about 10 minutes for a whole movie. The thing you have to consider is that other_transcode cannot process mp4s only mkv files, so you have to do a lossless conversion first, but even with the time added for that it is incredibly fast. Of cause you have to learn it again, but in my opinion it is worth the effort